# How can I search for mixed-case tag names in an ATOM XML document?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, atom-feed

I am working with the Google API, and they offer the option of returning JSON or ATOM. ATOM looks like XML syntax, and I want to use BeautifulSoup to parse it.

I have no problem turning that into a BeautifulSoup object, but I'm having a hard time locating the element. Taking a paragraph of the ATOM document as an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

feed = """
<cse:DataObject type="cse_thumbnail">
        <cse:Attribute name="width" value="160"/>
        <cse:Attribute name="height" value="160"/>
        <cse:Attribute name="src" value="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAUAShHrU8LK9MLEMEcfg-rtYgLzaxUP-j30lNJJdP1P6FBdVIziH4LTY"/>
</cse:DataObject>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(feed)

print soup.find_all("cse:Attribute", {"value":"160"})
```

... it returns an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm.. very strange. If I change the inner tags name to something completely different from the original `Attribute`, f.e `<cse:p...`, `find_all("cse:p", {"value":"160"})` able to return the tags

Comment: @har07 in the example you use – `cse:p` – it works because the tag name is all lowercase. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29901549) for more details.

Comment: Beautiful Soup is an HTML parser, whose main strength is parsing messy tag soup. If you want to parse well formatted XML, you should use an XML parser, like lxml, rather than abusing an HTML parser to read XML.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written parses the XML as though it were HTML, and because HTML is case-insensitive, BeautifulSoup [converts all tag names to lowercase](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems):

> Because [HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax), all three HTML parsers convert tag and attribute names to lowercase. That is, the markup `<TAG></TAG>` is converted to `<tag></tag>`. If you want to preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to [*parse the document as XML*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml).

Searching for a lowercased version of the tag works just fine:

```
>>> soup.find_all("cse:attribute", {"value":"160"})
[<cse:attribute name="width" value="160"></cse:attribute>, 
 <cse:attribute name="height" value="160"></cse:attribute>]
```

As the quoted text mentions, an alternative is to use an XML parser, which will preserve case. However, BeautifulSoup with the lxml parser strips namespaces from tag names ...

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(feed, "xml")
>>> soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataObject type="cse_thumbnail">
<Attribute name="width" value="160"/>
<Attribute name="height" value="160"/>
<Attribute name="src" value="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAUAShHrU8LK9MLEMEcfg-rtYgLzaxUP-j30lNJJdP1P6FBdVIziH4LTY"/>
</DataObject>
>>> soup.find_all("cse:Attribute", {"value":"160"})
[]
>>> soup.find_all("cse:attribute", {"value":"160"})
[]
>>> soup.find_all("Attribute", {"value":"160"})
[<Attribute name="width" value="160"/>,
 <Attribute name="height" value="160"/>]
```

... which may not be what you want.